# Add an AND clause only if a parameter is not null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2012, I need to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'Foo'
DECLARE @someINT INT = NULL

SELECT
    *
FROM
    myTable
WHERE
    Name = @name 
<IF @someINT IS NOT NULL>
    AND SomeInt = @someINT 
</IF>
```

The `AND` clause should only exist if @someINT  is not null.  Otherwise, we don't even do the `AND`.

Comment: `AND SomeInt = ISNULL(@SomeINT,SomeInt)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE Name = @name 
  AND (@someINT IS NULL OR SomeInt = @someINT)
```

Comment: that's it.  I'll mark as the answer in 12 minutes when it let's me :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another options is

```
WHERE Name = @name 
  and someInt = Isnull(@someINT , someInt)
```